# Is Modernizr covering the prefix for css?

Tags: css, html

Sorry for the silly question, but I am really beginner and I need your help.
I added modernizr-2.8.3.min.js in my website.
I visited the modernizr home page, but I don't understand how to download it.
Then, I found this modernizr file in the html5 boilerplate.
When I add this in my ,  is this helping me not to add vendor prefix?
Or, if I do not do anything with modernizr, should I use some kind of 'prefix free' file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Modernizr is a javascript library that detects the browser features. You can use it two ways.

1. Just include this in your file.
   `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.js">`
2. Go to https://modernizr.com/download?setclasses and select the features you want modernizer to detect. I can see how this can be confusing if you are a beginner so I suggest that you use the first option.

Once you include this in your html change your html tag to this `<html class="no-js">` and when you see your page in the browser you will see something like this.

`<html class=" js no-flexbox no-canvas no-canvastext no-webgl no-touch no-geolocation no-borderimage no-borderradius no-boxshadow no-textshadow no-opacity no-cssanimations no-csscolumns no-cssgradients ... etc">`

Now you can write your css for regular browsers and the one that doesn't support your feature.

So if you want to add gradients to `<div class="gradient">` for regular browsers you do something like this.

```
div.gradient{
  background: linear-gradient(red, yellow);
}
```

but for browsers that doesn't support border-radius modernizr adds `no-borderradius` to your html tag, see above. So for these browsers you can write your css like this to ensure a consistent view.

```
.no-cssgradients div.gradient{
  background: url("glossybackground.png");
}
```